# AngularJS + Directive to set input box value without space, lowercase, avoid special characters

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set directive to set input value with out space, lowercase and avoid special character while pressing.

Below code is to remove white spaces, and trying to set lowercase and avoid special character in same directive but failed

Trying to change the input box value after key press but last alphabet remain as it like UPPERCASE

```
app.directive('restrictField', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        restrictField: '='
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      var regex = /\s/g;    
      scope.$watch('restrictField', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != oldValue && regex.test(newValue)) {
          scope.restrictField = newValue.toLowerCase().replace(regex, '');
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: 2 things I noticed, you may want to change your restrict to just 'A', since this seems like it's just an attribute directive and also you may want to fire this directive on a keyup event instead of using a watch. What are the results you're getting so far?

Comment: Yes, I am not that good in angularjs. So Just trying

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of your condition. You'll transform `newValue` to lower case only if newValue contains white space.
Try this:

```
scope.$watch('restrictField', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        scope.restrictField = newValue.toLowerCase().replace(regex, '');
    }
});
```